# Firebase login with facebook -how to get larger profile image -javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to get user profile image in large dimension and can't make it happen. after login I get authFacebook.user.photoURL contains 100*100 px.

I also tried

```
graph.facebook.com/{{authFacebook.user.uid}}/picture?width=800
```

but it's not working.

Any idea? thanks?

```
login: function() {
        // Create facebook auth provider and add scope
        var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()

        // Sign in using facebook provider
        return firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(authFacebook) {
            accessToken = authFacebook.credential.accessToken;
            localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken);
            var user = Auth.getProfile(authFacebook.user.uid).$loaded();

            user.then(function(profile) {
                if (profile.name == undefined) {
                    //now authFacebook.user.photoURL contains 100*100 px
                }
            }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        // The email of the user's account used.
        var email = error.email;
        // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
        var credential = error.credential;
        // ...
      });
        })
    },
```

Comment: that's what I'm looking for, can you share the final code? I'm using facebook popup with firebase too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to get the facebook User id from the user providerData object:

`https://graph.facebook.com/{{authFacebook.user.providerData[fbIndex].uid}}/picture?width=800`

Comment: thany you, works! just a question. what is the meaning of fbIndex? when there may be more than 1 index?

Comment: If you only have one provider, then it should be 0 but Firebase Auth allows you to link additional providers. You can have one Firebase User with Google, Facebook, Twitter, GitHub and Password providers. The user is able to login with any of these linked auth providers. This is why there could be more than one element in the providerData array.